# jQuery Plugin: Make jQuery Variable Accessible Across all Plugin Functions

Tags: jquery, scope

I'm missing something fundamental with variable scope within a jQuery plugin.  The following is a jQuery plugin stub (based mostly off the jQuery.com documentation).

I'd like to make the variables (`$test` and `test`) available to all functions within the plugin.

In the example code below, the variable test writes 'hello' to the console as expected.

However, the variable `$test` writes jQuery() to the console.

Questions:
(a) Why doesn't `$test` write jQuery(div#test) to the console?
(b) What's best practice for making a jQuery variable (or any other variable) available across all functions.  e.g. similar to a class level variable in a .net class.

```
(function ($) {

var settings = {
};

var methods = {
    init: function (options) { if (options) { $.extend(settings, options); } return init(this, settings); }
};

$.fn.scopetest = function (method) {
    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery plugin');
    }
};

var $test = $('#test');
var test = 'hello';

var init = function (object, settings) {
    return object.each(function () {

        console.log($test);
        console.log(test);
    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with options:

```
(function ($) {

var options = {
        option1: "some_value",
        option2: "another_value",
        ...
    }
var settings = {
    };
```

Reference like this from your functions:

```
var self = this;
alert( self.options.option1 );
```

Or:

```
var self = this,
    o = self.options;
alert( o.option1);
```

Also have a look at the Jquery [widget factory plugin layout](http://ajpiano.com/widgetfactory/#slide1), which is close to yours, but which I like even better.

```
(function( $, window) {

    $.widget("widge_name", $.widget, {

        options: {
        ...
        },
        init: function(param_1, param_2) {
        ...
        },
        _create: function() {
        ...
        },
        some_function_A: function(param3, param4) {
        ...
        }
        some_function_B: function(param3, param4) {
        var self = this;
        // run some_function_A 
        self.some_function_A("foo","bar");
        }
  });
}) (jQuery,this);
```

This way you can call other functions the same way using *self* like above.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior here. If I define options like this:

    var options = {
        test1: 'test',
        test2: $('#test')
    };

I can access options.test1 and options.test2 (no need to define self) but a console.log on test2 writes jQuery().

Comment: hm. tried without the return object.each(function () {}? Just console.

Comment: I'm still missing something fundamental here. After looking at this again I see options (and all functions) are within the widget declaration. Does this mean the only way to have a variable across all functions is to restructure the plugin?

Comment: Removing "return object.each(function () {" results in the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

- Why doesn't $test write jQuery(div#test) to the console?

  Because, there is no such element with the id `test` in the DOM. So, jQuery returns empty collection `jQuery()`.
- What's best practice for making a jQuery variable (or any other variable) available across all functions?

  I am not sure about best practices, but if i have to make a variable to be accessible globally, i would associate the variable with `window` object. Like,

  `window.$test = $('#test');`
  `window.test = 'Hello';`

and access them, with `window` object (Eg: `alert(window.$test);`) or simply with the variable name `alert($test);`

Comment: The element does exist. If the console.log($('#test')); statement is moved to within the init function the expected output is returned.  
The intention here is NOT to declare a global variable across all plugins but rather to create a private variable to a plugin (available across all functions within the plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, leaving the var $test statement but moving the assignment into the init function seems to work.  So there seems to be an issue using $ unless it's inside a function.  Will use this as a workaround until a better solution is found.

```
(function ($) {

var settings = {
};

var methods = {
    init: function (options) { if (options) { $.extend(settings, options); } return init(this, settings); }
};

$.fn.scopetest = function (method) {

    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery plugin');
    }
};

var $test;
var test;

var init = function (object, settings) {

    return object.each(function () {

        $test = $('#test');
        test = 'hello';
        testfunc();
    });
}

var testfunc = function () {
    console.log($test);
    console.log(test);
}

})(jQuery);
```